# Is AIC appropriate for comparing non linear models?

Tags: r, nonlinear-regression, aic

In R, when trying to compare non linear models with AIC, you can use the function `AIC` on an `nls` object, which is the least squares estimates of the parameters of a model obtained using the function `nls`. However, in the documentation of the function `AIC`, you can read :

> "The theory of AIC requires that the log-likelihood has been
> maximized: whereas AIC can be computed for models not fitted by
> maximum likelihood, their AIC values should not be compared."

If I'm right, an nls object is not a model fitted by maximum likelihood but by least squares method. In consequence, the obtained values of AIC can not be compared. Why is that ? Should I manually calculate AIC in order to compare models fitted with `nls`? Is AIC appropriate for comparing non linear models?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, AIC (or AICc) are still "generally appropriate". We make the assumption of a Gaussian error (see below).

Avoid computing AIC manually if both models are of the same type, that said: `Comparing across model types requires attention to detail to make sure that parameters are counted using similar rules, and that additive constants are consistently included or not.` (from: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2010-August/250839.html)

For more information type `stats:::logLik.nls` to see for how the log-likelihood is calculated for `nls` fitted models as a function of their residuals and their associated weights. (Effectively it is just a  Gaussian log-likelihood of the weighted residuals.)

Comment: One additional point: Both models being compared need to have been fit with the same weighting method.