How to compare two non linear model fits
I am working with two datasets containing leaf parameters (gas exchange, temperature, and humidity). Each dataset is from a sampling site. I have used an NLS model to fit the gas exchange using temperature and humidity. Now I would like to know if both sites are different in leaf gas exchange, first I thought maybe a simple t-test on all three parameters would be ok but then I thought it would be better to test if the models themselves are different, but I am not sure what is the best way to do it.
If this were a linear model I would compare slopes but has an exponential component. should I go with a nested approach to test the likelihood ratio or is there any better and simpler way to test if they are different?
Any help or comment is appreciated

Check out model selection criteria. AICc, BIC, and so on.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Check out this post: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/492670/is-aic-appropriate-for-comparing-non-linear-models
